# How do remove Add To Cart button after a product is added in woo-commerce?

Tags: woocommerce

I want to remove the Add to Cart button and display View Cart in its place,after product is added in woo-commerce.
How do i do so?
Please give some hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i have been implementing for my projects
add following code in function.php to deregister the js which add view cart button along with add to cart button

```
wp_deregister_script('wc-add-to-cart');

wp_register_script('wc-add-to-cart', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/js/add-to-cart-multi.js' , array( 'jquery' ), WC_VERSION, TRUE);

wp_enqueue_script('wc-add-to-cart');
```

Now you need to tweak that js that we have deregistered and now we need to make a new js file named `add-to-cart-multi.js`

Following code goes in this newly created file

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {

    // wc_add_to_cart_params is required to continue, ensure the object exists
    if ( typeof wc_add_to_cart_params === 'undefined' )
        return false;

    // Ajax add to cart
    $( document ).on( 'click', '.add_to_cart_button', function(e) {

        // AJAX add to cart request
        var $thisbutton = $( this );

        if ( $thisbutton.is( '.product_type_simple' ) ) {

            if ( ! $thisbutton.attr( 'data-product_id' ) )
                return true;

            $thisbutton.removeClass( 'added' );
            $thisbutton.addClass( 'loading' );

            var data = {
                action: 'woocommerce_add_to_cart',
            };

            $.each( $thisbutton.data(), function( key, value ) {
                data[key] = value;
            });

            // Trigger event
            $( 'body' ).trigger( 'adding_to_cart', [ $thisbutton, data ] );

            // Ajax action
            $.post( wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url, data, function( response ) {

                if ( ! response )
                    return;

                var this_page = window.location.toString();

                this_page = this_page.replace( 'add-to-cart', 'added-to-cart' );

                if ( response.error && response.product_url ) {
                    window.location = response.product_url;
                    return;
                }

                // Redirect to cart option
                if ( wc_add_to_cart_params.cart_redirect_after_add === 'yes' ) {

                    window.location = wc_add_to_cart_params.cart_url;
                    return;

                } else {

                    $thisbutton.removeClass( 'loading' );

                    fragments = response.fragments;
                    cart_hash = response.cart_hash;

                    // Block fragments class
                    if ( fragments ) {
                        $.each( fragments, function( key, value ) {
                            $( key ).addClass( 'updating' );
                        });
                    }

                    // Block widgets and fragments
                    $( '.shop_table.cart, .updating, .cart_totals' ).fadeTo( '400', '0.6' ).block({
                        message: null,
                        overlayCSS: {
                            opacity: 0.6
                        }
                    });

                    // Changes button classes
                    $thisbutton.addClass( 'added' );
                    $thisbutton.addClass( 'hide' );
                    // View cart text
                    if ( ! wc_add_to_cart_params.is_cart && $thisbutton.parent().find( '.added_to_cart' ).size() === 0 ) {
                        $thisbutton.after( ' <a href="' + wc_add_to_cart_params.cart_url + '" class="add-cart button added_to_cart wc-forward" title="' +
                            wc_add_to_cart_params.i18n_view_cart + '"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>' );
                    }

                    // Replace fragments
                    if ( fragments ) {
                        $.each( fragments, function( key, value ) {
                            $( key ).replaceWith( value );
                        });
                    }

                    // Unblock
                    $( '.widget_shopping_cart, .updating' ).stop( true ).css( 'opacity', '1' ).unblock();

                    // Cart page elements
                    $( '.shop_table.cart' ).load( this_page + ' .shop_table.cart:eq(0) > *', function() {

                        $( '.shop_table.cart' ).stop( true ).css( 'opacity', '1' ).unblock();

                        $( 'body' ).trigger( 'cart_page_refreshed' );
                    });

                    $( '.cart_totals' ).load( this_page + ' .cart_totals:eq(0) > *', function() {
                        $( '.cart_totals' ).stop( true ).css( 'opacity', '1' ).unblock();
                    });

                    // Trigger event so themes can refresh other areas
                    $( 'body' ).trigger( 'added_to_cart', [ fragments, cart_hash ] );
                }
            });

            return false;

        }

        return true;
    });

});
```

On line number 77 i have added `class="hide"` using code

`$thisbutton.addClass( 'hide' );`

So hide basically hides the add to cart button

And did some more modifications i think to the code , but i dont remember it now what was it.

I hope this helps somebody

Comment: Deregister add-to-cart.min.js, copy add-to-cart.js to child theme, register it. When editing it, locate onAddToCart() method added in the AddToCartHandler class (AddToCartHandler.prototype.onAddToCart) and inside it, where the success function is located just after $( document.body ).trigger( 'added_to_cart', [ response.fragments, response.cart_hash, $thisbutton ] ); add the following generic code: $('.wrapped-button-in-div').find('button.added').remove(); as this will find the button and remove it after the class 'added' is added. Way less complicated solution.

Answer (score 0):

Works easily using just CSS on your theme/child style:

```
.add_to_cart_button.added {display:none !important;}
```

Answer (score -1):

i stumbled across this whilst looking to do eaxctly the same thing, and although i couldn't get the js to work i did notice when looking for the added `.hide` class that woo adds an `.added` class to the 'add to cart' button once it's been clicked anyway, so adding the following into my theme's css file did the job nicely.

```
a.button.product_type_simple.add_to_cart_button.ajax_add_to_cart.added {
    display: none;
}
```

i then simply styled the 'view cart' button to appear in its place, using this to target it:

```
a.added_to_cart {
    //do your thing
}
```

hope that's helpful to someone.